# Why does the ENTRYPOINT log output but not the CMD or RUN in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

In this Dockerfile i have an `ENTRYPOINT` that calls a script that simply logs an echo "testing". This output works locally when I build and run the Dockerfile. It also logs to cloudwatch when I use in conjunction with a docker-compose for aws.

However the `RUN` and `CMD` commands do not output anything to the console or cloudwatch, how do i see their output? I would expect at least some errors

```
ENTRYPOINT bash -c "/migrate.sh"

WORKDIR /
RUN yarn
CMD ["yarn migration:run", "dist/src/main"]
```

I'm building just with `docker build -t test:test .` then `docker run <imagename>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RUN` statement in the Dockerfile is only invoked when you build the container (at which point you should see the output of yarn in this case). When you `docker run` the container it will just execute the ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD (in this case the output of the ENTRYPOINT as there is no CMD)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for RUN / ENTRYPOINT. I had omitted CMD from the question, which i've now put back, but that CMD command also does not log anything?

Comment: What happens with the Dockerfile you have (now) is that, when you launch a container (either locally with `docker run` or with a runtask API in ECS) you are actually running `/migrate.sh yarn migration:run dist/src/main` (because they get concatenated - [this is a good article for background](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint)). Anything that that concatenated command will spit to stdout is your log (and should be captured).